# Solspace user registration via ajax

Tags: ajax, solspace-user, solspace, registration

Is this possible? I've been searching and  have not been successful in finding any solid answers. I've tried submitting the user registration form with ajax and it just returns the expected html page.  I hope I'm not just missing some parameter.

** edit **
figured out that you can submit, if successful you will get the expected response. If their are errors you will get undesirable response back. It a normal Expression Engine error page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for logging into ExpressionEngine with ajax and showing the appropriate error, you would just modify the code where it checks for the error messages it returns to display to the user. You will need more conditions for the required fields.

```
function displayAjaxMessage(message, response_id)
{
    if(typeof(response_id)==="undefined") response_id = "#form-message";
    $(response_id).html(message);
    $(response_id).show();
}

// using the jquery validate library 
$("#register-form").validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        password_confirm: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#register_confirm_password"
        },
    },

    submitHandler: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#register-form").attr("action"),
            data: $("#register-form").serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            type: 'POST',

            error: function (jxhr, msg, err) 
            {
                $('#register-form').append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
            },

            success: function(html, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                if (html.match(/<title>Error<\/title>/)) 
                {
                    var error = $(html).find('ul li:first').text(); 

                    if(error == "The username you chose is not available")
                    {
                        displayAjaxMessage("This email address is already registered",  "#register-form-message");
                    } else {
                        displayAjaxMessage(error,  "#register-form-message");
                    }
                } else {
                    $("#register-form").hide();
                    displayAjaxMessage("Thanks! You can now login!",  "#register-form-message");
                }
            }
        });
    } 
});
```